# getting error with OperationalError at /admin/login/ no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have created a virtual environment .
Using django 1.8.4

I ran `python manage.py migrate`,
created the superadmin and
after that on admin login getting error

> OperationalError at /admin/login/ no such table: auth_user

in setting.py

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` as well?

Comment: @TimWoocker yes i had.. still getting the same error

Comment: do you have `"django.contrib.auth"` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: and did you run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Don’t use Django 1.8. It does not receive security updates and is insecure. Switch to Python 3 and the latest Django 2.2.x if possible.